# Convert array of strings to field name

Tags: go

Newbie question:
I want to print various variables of a library (is that the correct name? `reflect.TypeOf(servers)` gives `[]lib.Server`)

I want to do something like this, but this obviously does not work:

```
servers, err := GetClient().GetServers() //call to external API

serverVariables := []string{}
serverVariables = append(serverVariables, "Name")
serverVariables = append(serverVariables, "IPAddress")

for _, server := range servers {
   for _,element := range serverVariables {
     fmt.Println(server.element)
   }
}
```

What I already can do is the following (but I want to do it using the above approach):

```
servers, err := GetClient().GetServers() //call to external API

for _, server := range servers {
   fmt.Println(server.Name)
   fmt.Println(server.IPAddress)
}
```

giving the following output:

```
ServerNameOne
192.168.0.1
ServerNameTwo
192.168.0.2
```

Comment: Do you want to create a slice of servers that contains details(Name, IPAddress) for each server?

Comment: No, `servers` is already holding all the details on multiple servers, where each server has the elements `Name` and `IPAddress`. Will update the question a bit

Comment: I just don't understand what you want to print out?

Comment: see my multiple edits to make it more clear hopefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reflection is what you probably want to use:

```
for _, server := range servers {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(server)
    for _, element := range serverVariables {
        fmt.Println(v.FieldByName(element))
    }
}
```

You should also change `serverVariables` initialization to be `serverVariables := []string{}`

Playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/s_kzIJ7-B7

It seems to me that you have experience in some dynamic language like Python or JavaScript. Go is compiled and strongly typed. Besides reflection being slower, when using it compiler can't help you with finding basic errors in your code and what is most important you lose type of the accessed variable.
More info on http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection

So I strongly recommend you to keep your current approach:

```
for _, server := range servers {
   fmt.Println(server.Name)
   fmt.Println(server.IPAddress)
}
```

Comment: You're quite right that I come from JS and Python ;-) the serverVariables initialization was indeed wrong in this example, because I copy/pasted it from my original source code

Comment: It works, thanks! I am aware now that the compiler will not catch typos and stuff when using the `FieldByName` approach

Comment: small additional question, is `fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(server).FieldByName(element))` faster/better then using an additional variable `v` as you did?

Comment: It's actually slower, because it has to create reflect.Value for every field you want to read.

Comment: indeed, could have thought of that myself ;-)